# Power bi Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I made this formula  `= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "test_column", each test_column(Query1[OrderID], Query1[#"Action Type"], Query1[Without_WWO_Assign], Query1[Without_WWO_Shipped], Query1[Assign], Query1[Shipped], [Index]))`  I tried it in 2 different files. In one it works correctly in second one it gives error "Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation." The only difference between this two is that in one of them there are joined table. Is it can make this error?

Comment: That's not a full query. Open the Advanced editor to copy the full source. The cyclic error means you're building a table that relies on itself.